# how to customize redQueryBuilder

Tags: javascript, jquery, redquerybuilder

i just want to customize redquerbuilder. Currently it shows its own default table names like city country etc. i just want to connect this to my own database please help .for database i use MYSQL. Here is the URL of redquerbuilder. [http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/] and from here i downloaded the source code [https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder]

Answer (score 0):

RedQueryBuilder is just the component that provides the boolean query user interface. The GAE page you link to is an example usage, the source code is available on github.

However I'd suggest you look at other projects like: http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/ that seem to be more popular and actively developed.

FWIW I'm the original author of RedQueryBuilder